# trying to display datepicker in Impromptu prompt box?

Tags: datepicker, impromptu

I am trying to display ui datepicker ctrl in prompt box [ using impromptu jquery script]. Following is my code what I am trying.

```
var txt = 'Date: <input id="datepicker" name="date_picker" type="text" />';
$.prompt(txt).$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

as per blog - impromptu this should work but it doesn't display the datepicker 
control in the prompt box!!

Please let me know if someone has any idea.

just for note:

script included in following order

ui.core.js
ui.draggable.js
ui.resizable.js
ui.datepicker.js
Impromptu.js

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax needs a little adjustment:

```
var txt = 'Date: <input id="datepicker" name="date_picker" type="text" />';
$.prompt(txt);
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

You may need to also adjust the z-index of the datepicker in the css, at least in the old versions om impromptu this was true.